# Showing that, for $|a|>3$ and $n\geq1$, the function $f(z)=e^z-az^n$ has exactly $n$ roots (all simple and different) in the open unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots, holomorphic-functions, rouches-theorem

> Let $|a|>3$, $n\geq1$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, 
>   then the function $$f(z)=e^z-az^n$$ 
>   has exactly $n$ roots in the disc $\{z\mid|z|<1\}$, and that they are all simple.
>
> Hint: look at $f(z)-f'(z)$

I am not sure how do I even approach proving existence of roots, rather then proving maybe that the function is not vanishing (and then it has logarithm, and root, but how do I show existence of n roots?)

I thought also of maybe using somehow Rouche's Theorem, since:

$$f(z)-f'(z)=az^{n-1}\cdot(n-z)$$

and from there, that showing that $f$ has $n$ roots in the disk.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that if $a>e$, the equation $az^n=e^z$ admit $n$ roots in the unit disk - Rouché theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1734959/show-that-if-ae-the-equation-azn-ez-admit-n-roots-in-the-unit-disk-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proving existence of roots by using [Rouché's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem) is a good idea. Let $g(z)=az^n$ then for $|z|=1$,
$$|g(z)|=|a|>3>|e^z|=e^{\cos(t)}=|f(z)-g(z)|$$
where $t\in [0,2\pi)$.
What may we conclude?

Moreover if $|w|<1$ and $f(w)=e^w-aw^n=0$ then $w$ is NOT simple iff
$$0=f'(w)=e^w-anw^{n-1}=aw^{n-1}(w-n)$$
which holds iff $w=0$ which is not a root because $f(w)=1$. So $w$ is simple.

Answer (score 1):

The fast way is with Rouche's Theorem.

Alternatively, set $f_t(z)=az^n-te^z$.

Observe that, $f_t(z)\ne 0$, for $|z|=1$, and $t\in [0,1]$, and that the
$$
g(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{f_t'(z)\,dz}{f_t(z)}=\text{number of roots of $f$ is $\{|z|<1\}$} \in \mathbb Z
$$
Meanwhile, $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, and hence constant. Thus 
$$
\text{number of roots of $f$ is $\{|z|<1\}$}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{f'(z)\,dz}{f(z)}=g(1) \\=g(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{nz^{n-1}\,dz}{z^n}=n.
$$

Comment: Why is $g(t)$ is the number of roots of f? 
From the argument principle, g(t) is the number of zeros of f minus the number of poles in f (including their order). why is it equal to the number of roots?

Comment: Clearly, $f_t$ DOES NOT have any poles or other singularities in the disk, as it is entire analytic.

Comment: Yes, in this case it is equal to the number of zeros with their order. why is it the number of roots? (I know, I am confused with the definitions)

Comment: Zeros and roots is the same thing, in Complex Analysis.

Comment: @user3708158 : If there is made a distinction, zeros are the zero-value points of a function, while roots are the solutions of an equation. In the arabic original the words for "(square, cubic,...) roots" and "solution" had the same abbreviation, and so Fibonacci in "Liber abaci" translated them the same, which is since traditional.