# Show that the equation $e^z=az^n$ has $n$ solutions in the unit disc centred at the origin counting multiplicity.

Tags: complex-analysis, rouches-theorem

Let $a \in \mathbb{C}$ be such that $|a| > e$. Show that the equation $e^z=az^n$ has $n$ solutions in the disk $D_1(0)$ i.e. the unit disk centred at the origin counting multiplicity.

I think I'm supposed to use use Rouches theorem to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that if $a>e$, the equation $az^n=e^z$ admit $n$ roots in the unit disk - Rouché theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1734959/show-that-if-ae-the-equation-azn-ez-admit-n-roots-in-the-unit-disk-r)

Answer (score 2):

$|az^{n}| =|a| >e \geq |e^{z}|$ when $|z|=1$.  Apply Rouche's Theorem to conclude that $e^{z}-az^{n}$ and $az^{n}$ have the same number of zeros in the open unit disk.